# How to put a big equation in a single slide?

Tags: equations, slideshow

How to make a big equation fit in a single slide?

I have the following equation:

```
\begin{frame}

\begin{equation}
        \begin{split}
        (\lambda_1-2n+l+4)(\lambda_1-n-l+2)\leq l(n-l) 
        \\
        \implies \lambda_1^2+\lambda_1(6-3n)+(2n^2-2l-8n+8)\leq 0
        \\
    \implies \bigg \{ 2\lambda_1-\bigg(3n-6-\sqrt{8l+n^2-4n+4}\bigg )\bigg \}\bigg \{ 2\lambda_1-\bigg(3n-6+\sqrt{8l+n^2-4n+4}\bigg)\bigg \} \leq 0
        \\
        \implies  \frac{3n-6-\sqrt{8l+n^2-4n+4}}{2}\leq \lambda_1 \leq \frac{3n-6+\sqrt{8l+n^2-4n+4}}{2}
        \end{split}
        \end{equation}

\end{frame}
```

Whenever I am using `\begin{frame}` `\end{frame}` a part of my equation is going outside the frame.

How can I adjust the whole equation in a single slide?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a solution suggestion that performs alignment on the inequality symbols.

Aside: The `\bigg` sizing instructions are, in my opinion, excessive; `\big` and `\Big` suffice completely.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
(\lambda_1-2n+l+4)(\lambda_1-n-l+2) &\leq l(n-l) \\
\implies \lambda_1^2+\lambda_1(6-3n)+(2n^2-2l-8n+8) &\leq 0\\
\implies \Bigl\{ 2\lambda_1-\bigl(3n-6-\sqrt{8l+n^2-4n+4}\,\bigr )\Bigr \} \quad&\\
\times\Bigl\{ 2\lambda_1-\bigl(3n-6+\sqrt{8l+n^2-4n+4}\,\bigr)\Bigr\} &\leq 0 \\
\implies  \frac{3n-6-\sqrt{8l+n^2-4n+4}}{2}&\leq \lambda_1\\
\text{and}\quad 
\frac{3n-6+\sqrt{8l+n^2-4n+4}}{2} &\geq \lambda_1\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Here's a second solution, inspired by [@egreg's observation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/526685/5001) that a lot of space is taken up by the repeated term `\sqrt{8l+n^2-4n+4}`. Replacing it with the symbol `D`, rewriting the final row to use interval notation instead of a pair of inequalities, and aligning the rows on the `\implies` symbols instead of on the inequality symbols yields the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
&(\lambda_1-2n+l+4)(\lambda_1-n-l+2) \leq l(n-l)\\
\implies&\lambda_1^2-\lambda_1(3n-6)+(2n^2-2l-8n+8)\leq 0\\
\implies&\bigl( 2\lambda_1-(3n-6-D) \bigr) 
         \bigl( 2\lambda_1-(3n-6+D) \bigr) \leq 0 \\
\implies&\lambda_1\in\bigl[
         (\tfrac{3}{2}n-3)-\tfrac{1}{2}D, 
         (\tfrac{3}{2}n-3)+\tfrac{1}{2}D \bigr]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $D=\sqrt{(n-2)^2+8l}$\,.

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: wanted to know , why do we use \quad&

Comment: @Math_Freak - The single use of `\quad` pushes the first row of the two-row equation slightly to the left. The (intended) visual effect is to make clear that the absence of an equality symbol in that row isn't accidental. Without the `\quad`, the expressionsin curly braces would be perfectly aligned, maybe raising some questions in readers' minds as to what's going on.

Answer (score 9):

Much of the horizontal space is taken by the long square roots. Always presume that your audience is able to read, so you can use an abbreviation.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{align}
& (\lambda_1-2n+l+4)(\lambda_1-n-l+2)\leq l(n-l) \notag
\\
\implies\quad
& \lambda_1^2+\lambda_1(6-3n)+(2n^2-2l-8n+8)\leq 0 \notag
\\
\implies\quad
& \Bigl \{ 2\lambda_1-\bigl(3n-6-\sqrt{D}\,\bigr)\Bigr\}
  \Bigl \{ 2\lambda_1-\bigl(3n-6+\sqrt{D}\,\bigr)\Bigr \} \leq 0 \notag
\\
\implies\quad
& \frac{3n-6-\sqrt{D}}{2}\leq \lambda_1 \leq \frac{3n-6+\sqrt{D}}{2} \label{whatever}
\end{align}
where $D=8l+n^2-4n+4$.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

A vertically centered equation number would be very ambiguous, so I chose to set it at the bottom. I also reduced the size of the parentheses; note the `\,` to separate the vinculum from the closing parenthesis.

[image]

In case of need, the middle long equation could be split using `multlined` (this is why I loaded `mathtools`.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{align}
& (\lambda_1-2n+l+4)(\lambda_1-n-l+2)\leq l(n-l) \notag
\\
\implies\quad
& \lambda_1^2+\lambda_1(6-3n)+(2n^2-2l-8n+8)\leq 0 \notag
\\
\implies\quad
& \begin{multlined}[t]
  \Bigl \{ 2\lambda_1-\bigl(3n-6-\sqrt{D}\,\bigr)\Bigr\} \\
  \cdot \Bigl \{ 2\lambda_1-\bigl(3n-6+\sqrt{D}\,\bigr)\Bigr \} \leq 0 
  \end{multlined} \notag
\\
\implies\quad
& \frac{3n-6-\sqrt{D}}{2}\leq \lambda_1 \leq \frac{3n-6+\sqrt{D}}{2} \label{whatever}
\end{align}
where $D=8l+n^2-4n+4$.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, with the text typeset in sans serif, I'd avoid “l” as a variable.

Comment: You just taught me the word "vinculum". Cool.

Answer (score 4):

Inside a `split` you can specify an alignment point for each row using `&`, this greatly enhances the legibility of multi-line equations. Also, you'd have to split the very long lines into two lines as well. In the following I did so and move those continuing lines further to the right using `\qquad`.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage[]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
    &(\lambda_1-2n+l+4)(\lambda_1-n-l+2)\leq l(n-l)
      \\
    \implies &\lambda_1^2+\lambda_1(6-3n)+(2n^2-2l-8n+8)\leq 0
      \\
    \implies &\bigg \{ 2\lambda_1-\bigg(3n-6-\sqrt{8l+n^2-4n+4}\bigg )\bigg \}
      \\
      &\qquad\cdot\bigg \{ 2\lambda_1-\bigg(3n-6+\sqrt{8l+n^2-4n+4}\bigg)\bigg \} \leq 0
      \\
    \implies  &\frac{3n-6-\sqrt{8l+n^2-4n+4}}{2}
      \\
    &\qquad\leq \lambda_1 \leq \frac{3n-6+\sqrt{8l+n^2-4n+4}}{2}
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A possibility with the `gathered` environment, and `spreadlines` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{equation}
\begin{spreadlines}{-0.2ex}
 \begin{gathered}
 (\lambda_1-2n+l+4)(\lambda_1-n-l+2) \leq s l(n-l) \\
\Downarrow\\
  \lambda_1^2+\lambda_1(6-3n)+(2n^2-2l-8n+8)\leq 0 \\
\Downarrow \\
    \Bigl\{2\lambda_1-\Bigl(3n-6-\sqrt{8l+n^2-4n+4}\Bigr)\Bigr\}\cdot{}\qquad \\[0.5ex]
  \qquad{}\cdot\Bigl\{2\lambda_1-\Bigl(3n-6+\sqrt{8l+n^2-4n+4}\Bigr)\Bigr\}\leq 0 \\
\Downarrow \\
\mathclap{\frac{3n-6-\sqrt{8l+n^2-4n+4}}{2} \leq \lambda_1 \leq \frac{3n-6+\sqrt{8l+n^2-4n+4}}{2}}\\
  \end{gathered}
  \end{spreadlines}
 \end{equation}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't add anything to the OP. Just make the align correct by shrinking the frame and re-positioning the `&` inside the align environment.

Hope this helps.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[shrink=35]

\begin{equation}
\centering
\begin{split}
(\lambda_1-2n+l+4)(\lambda_1-n-l+2)\leq l(n-l) 
    &\\
    &\\\implies \lambda_1^2+\lambda_1(6-3n)+(2n^2-2l-8n+8)\leq 0
    &\\
&\\\implies \bigg \{ 2\lambda_1-\bigg(3n-6-\sqrt{8l+n^2-4n+4}\bigg )\bigg \}\bigg \{ 2\lambda_1-\bigg(3n-6+\sqrt{8l+n^2-4n+4}\bigg)\bigg \} \leq 0
    &\\
    &\\\implies  \frac{3n-6-\sqrt{8l+n^2-4n+4}}{2}\leq \lambda_1 \leq \frac{3n-6+\sqrt{8l+n^2-4n+4}}{2}
    \end{split}
    \end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```